# Can new decryption keys be issued without modifying the encrypted contents?

Tags: encryption, keys, algorithm-design, symmetric

I'm curious if there's an encryption scheme where content may be encrypted to a public key where the associated private key can generate new decryption keys for the same content. The goal is to publish data that is encrypted with a server's public key and allow the server to produce new decryption keys as needed.

Comment: Does the requirements include that the new decryption keys be prepared only from the original key pair, without access to the material that is (including was, and possibly will be) encrypted with the original public/encryption key? Should there be something the new decryption keys can do that the old private/decryption key does not, or vice versa? If not, what in the requirements is not met if the new decryption keys are (a copy of) the original private/decryption key?